# iTunes displays filenames instead of metadata for imported music

Tags: itunes

I'm using iTunes version 10.7.0.21.

With music I've imported to iTunes (having ripped it elsewhere), it displays the filename rather than the metadata. This results in track numbers being included in song titles, symbols missing, and long titles being cut off.

For example, '02 Where Did All The Love Go_' rather than 'Where Did All The Love Go?', or '09 Ladies And Gentleman (Roll The' instead of 'Ladies And Gentleman (Roll The Dice)'.

I've checked the metadata in Windows Explorer and it is very definitely all there, and it's all correct.

This doesn't happen with music I ripped directly into iTunes, so I guess re-ripping all the other CDs would be one way of fixing it, but it would be a laborious process and not much of a solution.

Is there any way I can tell iTunes to display the metadata for song titles rather than the filename?

Comment: Do you know what version the meta data is stored in?  The ID3 tagging should be using at least version V2.x for iTunes to read/write them.  You could also try using `get info` on the song to see what it thinks the tags are (probably blank if it's replacing with filenames etc).

Comment: They were ripped using Windows Media Player, not an earlier version of iTunes. I use iTunes to rip everything these days, but that's not much help for the older stuff in my digital music collection.

Comment: Windows media players users ID3 tagging as a secondary tagging system, incorporating it's own standard.  If you are checking these tags on a Windows machine, then chances are it knows how to read both standards.  They may be tagged, but chances are they are not ID3 tagged.  You will need to convert them.  I'm not at a Mac to check, but there is a Convert Tag Format option *somewhere* in iTunes (you may need to right click a track, or it may be in the menu bar) - have a hunt.  I'll convert these comments into an answer when I get to a Mac.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743220(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Brilliant, that seems like it'll solve it. Do you know which ID3 version would be the best one to convert to? The options it offers when right clicking and selecting 'Convert ID3 Tags' are 'none', 'v1.0', 'v1.1', 'v2.2', 'v2.3', and 'v2.4'. And make sure you write up an answer when you get the chance so I can give you rep.

Comment: iTunes uses 2.2 when it rips direct, but it will happily read the others.  I'd probably go for 2.3

Comment: 2.4 isn't readable by (for example) Windows Media Player on Windows 8 (according to Wikipedia), so 2.3 seems a safe bet.